# Mutating version of sortBy and orderBy

Tags: lodash

In lodash, the [`orderBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#orderBy) and [`sortBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.5#sortBy) functions create a new array. Isn't this not as performant as mutating the array? How come they made it do this, and this only? I can't find a mutate version, is there one?

Answer (score 1):

Take this thought with a grain of salt, since I am not a maintainer of the library.

There is likely a performance difference with not mutating the array, but the problem with mutation is that you are not able to be [functionally-pure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function), which would cause problems if you attempted to use it with the `_.chain()` method.

Another note is that ALL of the Lodash functions will ALWAYS be slower than their native counterparts, since they have a lot of extra functionality for helpers.

Lastly, there is not a Lodash method that does sorting / ordering, but you could use the native [Array.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method and write your own comparison function.